# QMainWindow with member QWidget and QLayout crashes on exit, how to fix that?

Tags: c++, qt

The following is a single-file QWidget program.

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
class MainWindow:public QMainWindow{
    QLabel lb;
    QWidget wgt;
    QVBoxLayout lout{&wgt};
public:
    MainWindow(){
        lout.addWidget(&lb);//line A
        setCentralWidget(&wgt);
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The program crashes on exit. The function-call trace on crash is

> system calls
> QObjectPrivate::deleteChildren()
> QWidget::~QWidget()
> QMainWindow::~MainWindow
> main

If line A is removed then there is no crash.

I want to figure out what causes the crash, and how to use member QWidget and QLayout without having a crash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you/solve your problem? If so, please consider upvoting and/or accepting them!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the problem *is* due to an attempt to free memory that wasn't allocated on the heap I don't think the `QMainWindow` destructor or a 'double-delete' is the culprit (as suggested elsewhere).

As well as deleting its children the `QObject` destructor will also remove itself from any parent's object hierarchy.  In the code shown `wgt` is a data member of `MainWindow` meaning `wgt`'s dtor will be invoked before that of the `MainWindow` instance.  Hence, by the time `~MainWindow` is invoked `wgt` is no longer a child and no attempt will be made to free it at that point.  So that's not the issue.

Instead the real problem is the order in which the data members `lb`, `lout` and `wgt` are declared in the `MainWindow` class...

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    QLabel      lb;
    QWidget     wgt;
    QVBoxLayout lout{&wgt};
```

The widget hierarchy is...

```
wgt
  \_lb
```

and the implicit construction order...

```
lb
lout
wgt
```

meaning the order in which the dtors is invoked is...

```
wgt
lout
lb
```

Thus, when `wgt` destructor is called `lb` is still a child and `wgt` will attempt to free it.  That's the cause of the problem in this particular case.  While it can be solved by allocating the various `QObject`s on the heap, an alternative solution would be to simply re-order the member declarations within `MainWindow` to ensure the correct order of construction and destruction...

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
    QWidget     wgt;
    QVBoxLayout lout{&wgt};
    QLabel      lb;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in this, this is an actual bug in Qt that is now closed - but **not** solved:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71545